# Best practice for working with DateTime in C# relative to a user's local timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, timezone

I have an application with discount/deals for items that need to be configured to be enabled between specific datetimes i.e. `1st January 2022 7:00 am` to `31st January 2022 5:00 pm`.

The user which sets these start and end dates can be based anywhere in the world but the end consumers need to observe these start and end dates relative to their local time.

For example, the user setting up the deal is in Malaysia `GMT+8` for their end consumers across Indonesia (which has 3 separate time zones `GMT+7`, `GMT+8` and `GMT+9`) as well as some other end consumers in New Zealand (which has daylight savings and alternates between `GMT+12` and `GMT+13`)

So, a consumer in `GMT+13` must observe the deal being available in `1st Jan 7am` while another consumer in `GMT+7` will observe it a few hours later but still `1st Jan 7am` in their local time.

They observe these deals 1. On an app on their phone and 2. In-store where they claim these deals. So even though consumers could change the time zone on their phone to see the deal being available sooner - they must go in-store to claim them and can only do so once the timezone of the store reaches the available time.

My current thought process is to store these without any time zone into using a `DateTime` type with `Unspecified` kind and any usage of this `DateTime` will be relative to the consumer/stores local time configured on the device. I don't see a way to do this with saving this date as `UTC`

Are there any alternative approaches?
Is there better support with this use case by using the new `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` structs?

Comment: DateTime is automatically stored as UTC and is converted to/from a string using the TimeZone setting of the PC.  You need to get the UTC times when store is open and closed and compare UTC time with store opening and closing times.

Comment: @jdweng, hey great point regarding UTC time of the store - I have added another scenario where some stores/consumers are in countries with daylight savings so this wouldn't work as the time will shift. Regarding storing of the DateTime, I can write a serializer to store it in a format like `yyyy-MM-dd hh:MM:ss`

Comment: @jdweng DateTime is stored internally as a number of ticks since 1-Jan-0001 00:00, plus flags for local or UTC. A localized DateTime has a different tick count than the equivalent UTC value, not just different flags.  Perhaps you're thinking of FILETIME.

Comment: @AaronZhong DST shouldn't affect your use case since it is only ambiguous outside of business hours. Just treat all your DateTime values as local time, since it's the local time that's important both in the app and in-store.

Comment: The timezone alters with DST so you do not need to handle a special case.  You just have to careful how you handle the stop open time and store closing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current thought process is to store these without any time zone into using a `DateTime` type with `Unspecified` kind and any usage of this `DateTime` will be relative to the consumer/stores local time configured on the device.

Yes, that would be appropriate for the scenario you described.

This is sometimes referred to as a "floating time".  You might also see it described as "television time", because such scenarios are common in broadcast television with regard to the time a show is aired.

Keep in mind the following:

- When you *store* or *transmit* these values, do not treat them as UTC or associate them with any particular offset.  Just use the date and time.
- When you *use* these values on the user's device, you can apply the local time zone without actually knowing what that time zone is.  For example, in .NET you can use `TimeZoneInfo.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Local`.  In JavaScript, you can use the `Date` object, etc.
- When you use these values *elsewhere*, such as in a back-end system, scheduler, or administrative UI, you will nee to know the user's time zone ID.  Treat the value as belonging to that user's time zone, then convert it to a `DateTimeOffset` before comparing it to other values.  For example:

  ```
  TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindBySystemTimeZoneId(userTZ);
  TimeSpan offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(dt);
  DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);

  if (dto >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow) ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the additional points - they're great! This may sound a bit crazy but the customers we're working with don't send us their store time zones (old systems that take forever to update), but we do get time zone info from consumer apps. So, for the third point there's additional complexity - in which case, do you see any issues with skipping the conversion to `DateTimeOffset` and only looking at Date and Time values?

Comment: If you don't know their time zone, and you're trying to compare to the time in some other time zone, then what would you expect to happen?  In general, such comparisons are meaningless.  There are many ways to obtain a user's time zone, such as calling an API on the device/browser,  looking it up from location, or asking them to pick from a list.